# How to get differences between two JSONs?

Tags: json, scala

I want to compare 2 JSON and get all the differences between them in Scala. For example, I would like to compare:

```
{"a":"aa", "b": "bb", "c":"cc" }
```

and

```
{"c":"cc", "a":"aa", "d":"dd"}
```

I'd like to get `b` and `d`.

Comment: Are there any additional constraints, i.e. JSON library/framework you're using? Do you want to compare complex JSON structures or just the flat ones as on the example?

Comment: What if both maps have identical keys but they map to different things? Say in first map you had `"a":"zz"`

Comment: @NorbertRadyk : i can use everything if it's compatible with gatling.  the most complex JSON that i can work with arrays. like that: {"a":{"b":"bb","c":"cc"},"d":"dd",...} thanks for the help!

Comment: @Akavall it may be good to have this information but not mandatory. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I used JSONassert that does the same thing.

For example,

```
String expected = "{id:1,name:\"Joe\",friends:[{id:2,name:\"Pat\",pets:[\"dog\"]},{id:3,name:\"Sue\",pets:[\"bird\",\"fish\"]}],pets:[]}";
String actual = "{id:1,name:\"Joe\",friends:[{id:2,name:\"Pat\",pets:[\"dog\"]},{id:3,name:\"Sue\",pets:[\"cat\",\"fish\"]}],pets:[]}"
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, actual, false);
```

it returns

```
friends[id=3].pets[]: Expected bird, but not found ; friends[id=3].pets[]: Contains cat, but not expected
```

source: http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/

Answer (score 6):

If it isn't a restriction you can use http://json4s.org/ it has a nice diff feature.

Follow an example based on question:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

val json1 = parse("""{"a":"aa", "b":"bb", "c":"cc"}""")
val json2 = parse("""{"c":"cc", "a":"aa", "d":"dd"}""")

val Diff(changed, added, deleted) = json1 diff json2
```

It will return:

```
changed: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue = JNothing
added: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List((d,JString(dd))))
deleted: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List((b,JString(bb))))
```

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Mind presenting an example? In the current form, it's more a comment not an answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer! my restriction is that i must use gatling. json4s seems to be good. i'll try to use it and i'll make a feedback.